# Transcribe audio file to text? i.e. speech-to-text

Tags: software-rec, audio, podcasts, speech-to-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speech recognition - MP3 to text software](https://superuser.com/questions/127929/speech-recognition-mp3-to-text-software)

Is there a piece of software that allows me to point it to e.g. an **mp3 file** of a podcast which it analyzes and creates a **text file transcription** of the audio?

Comment: Solution: [OpenAI's ASR](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718354/16704)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few software available to perform speech recognition (i.e. speech to text (STT)), but I am not sure to what extent they would be able to fulfill your needs. I guess the best solutions available are expensive. For instance, the Dragon NaturallySpeaking SDK should be able to do the job. Some free alternative exist though. Check CMU Sphinx or Microsoft's Speech Software Recognition for example.

To narrow down your research, you should take into consideration the system that you are using (Linux, BSD, Windows, etc) as well as the type of recording that you will use (are the speakers known in advance or not). This will impact the solutions that you can or cannot use. Also, beware that, afaik, speech recognition is far from being accurate.

Hope it helps!

[Sphinx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/)

[MS SAPI](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=sapi&productID=&DisplayLang=en)

[Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/products/sdk/SDK-frequently-asked-questions.asp)