# Are there any free voice transcription software?

Tags: software-rec, audio, recording, voice, transcription

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speech recognition - MP3 to text software](https://superuser.com/questions/127929/speech-recognition-mp3-to-text-software)

I have some 1-hour-long voice recordings containing useful information that I may need to look up in the future. Instead of transcribing them myself (which will take me many hours), I want to automate it using software. I don't need an accurate transcription; it's OK as long as I can get an idea of what was being talked about by skimming over the transcription. With this, I can quickly figure out which part of the audio contains the information I need, and is much more convenient than seeking randomly.

In theory I could write a program to split the audio into 3 minutes chucks and pipe them into Google Voice's free voicemail transcription service... But I hope there are better solutions. Do you know any free voice transcription software?

*Note: Free trials are also acceptable*

Comment: I think this generally one of those really hard CompSci problems. I was asked to be in a project to listen and transcribe long records once.

Comment: Once again, no clue as to the target operating system!

Comment: @nhinkle Um... that question is similar to mine but I think my requirement differs in that I'm looking for free software and I don't need good accuracy. Hopefully this does not fall into the definition of "duplicate".

Comment: @Dennis Windows or any free OS (Linux, FreeBSD, etc) that supports the x86 or x86-64 architeture is fine

Comment: I'd be surprised if you will someone offering such a potentially complex piece of software for free (unless of course, you are Google).  I found no such free software doing a search, and only found Dragon from Nuance.