# Converting sound / audio file to text files

Tags: audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speech recognition - MP3 to text software](https://superuser.com/questions/127929/speech-recognition-mp3-to-text-software)

How do I convert a sound / audio file (e.g. wma, mp3, wav) into a normal text file? (The text file should have the transcript of the sound / audio)

Comment: @slhck, the link provided only cover MP3 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a speech to text program.

you can actually do it in windows7 , because it has built into it one of the worst speech to text programs they make. . . nevermind.

Dragon naturally speaking. if I told you more it would sound like a commertial :-)

The problem is, all of the speech to text requires training the program to understand.  Feeding it what you usually write (or other video transripts) and training it with your actual voice.
When it comes to trying to grab 2-4 voices off of a conversation , it is so hit and miss , that you would spend more time fixing it than if you type it from scratch.
It is totally possible, and (again) should be tried.

Example: Once trained , I should be typing this with it, because it would spell better than I do, fix my grammer, and punctuate properly.  But I can work all night getting it perfect, then wake up in the morning with a fresh voice and it will give me trouble again.  Changing mics, or changing the position of the mic, or changing the levels being fed to it a lot, will also make it rough until it learns again.

Which leaves "transcribing"  you talk your way through the whole movie (wearing headphones), re-speaking all the parts, then go back over the whole document making corrections.  I have used this method before to transcribe a legal deposition video.

Comment: I do agree with you but was wondering if there are such application that is the best among its peers and worth trying it. It should be able to cater as many audio / sound format (not just mp3) only and should be able to provide up to 90% accuracy of converting the sound to text.

Comment: I suspect that there is very high level software, or even dedicated machines , that are way more capable than what they sell in the store for me.  I thought one time that a Presidents speech on the media was being close captioned live by a machine , instead of a human, because it made "sounds the same" errors vrses keyboard miss errors.

Comment: tell me more about this very high level software and where can I find them

Comment: I do not know. here is a search that gets to some info http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=qdr:y&source=hp&q=allintext:+media+broadcasting+speech+recognition&pbx=1&oq=allintext:+media+broadcasting+speech+recognition&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=14757l17955l2l18501l11l11l0l0l0l0l219l1547l3.6.2l11l0&tbo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5bd719b69316594c&biw=1053&bih=749